# Do I need the latest .NET Core patch to run new code?

Tags: .net-core

I've always published my .NET Core apps - both ASP.NET and Console apps - in "Self-Contained" mode. This is so I don't have to worry about installing anything on the servers. With a few dozen apps at about 70MB each, I'm re-thinking using Framework-Dependent instead.

My development machine has .NET Runtime 5.0.2, and that patch version (the third number) seems to update pretty often. If my server has .NET Runtime 5.0.0, will it always handle code built on a machine with 5.0.x? From what I've read, minor versions like 5.1 would require the server to be updated, but what about patch versions? Is there any reasonable possibility that my code wouldn't run properly if the server doesn't have the latest patch?

Or is it a "check the release notes every time" kind of deal?

Comment: No. The version you target in the project matters most.  Which should be 5.0, any runtime patch version can tackle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Or is it a "check the release notes every time" kind of deal?* This one. No one knows. The [5.0.2](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/5.0/5.0.2/5.0.2.md) resolved a denial of service on the kestrel server. It was a security fix. The [5.0.1](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/5.0/5.0.1/5.0.1.md) instead resolved various bugs in certain methods/libraries.

Clearly there is a small possibility that your code was leveraging a bug that is being fixed, and after the patch it will break (very very rarely it should happen. They are very careful about breaking changes). Or perhaps one day your code will break because something caused a rarely used piece of code that uses a buggy .NET method to run. Ah, the life of the programmer, always full of mystery and adventure

Comment: Seems like odds are practically zero for any normal stuff I'd be doing, so maybe I'll just not worry about it except on super mission critical stuff. Thanks